# How can I annotate an image in IPython?

Tags: ipython

I'm using the IPython Notebook. So far all I've got is:

```
from IPython.core.display import Image
Image(filename='gibbs.png')
```

Which indeed displays the image very well. What I want now is to add a few textboxes and arrows pointing at specific zones in the picture, ideally all within code (instead of drag-and-dropping).

Something tells me I'll probably have to do it in Matplotlib, but I want to know what are the best practices.

Comment: Yes, you will probably have to use something like matplotlib or PIL to annotate the image. Although I guess you could embed it in HTML, and annotate it with HTML & CSS, but that's probably more fiddly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use matplotlib to do this. The [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) function will allow you to include arrows and text. If you want the text without the arrow, then omit the "arrowprops" part. If you want the arrow but not text, then just include an empty string.

Try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = plt.imread('gibbs.png')

plt.imshow(data)

plt.annotate('Label A',xy=(81,130),xytext=(150,200),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red'))

plt.show()
```

Here is the output that I get, assuming that you are using a png of J. Willard Gibbs:
[image]